# Filter pyspark dataframe looping through dates

Tags: pyspark

I am quite new to pyspark. I am trying to filter a pyspark dataframe on dates iteratively. I am trying to create some function that can filter through dates to query one week's data for each month in a given date range.

My input table looks something like this and this is partitioned on date

| date | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | abc |
| 2018-01-02 | abc |
| 2018-01-02 | xyz |
| 2018-01-02 | ghk |

So I would ideally define:
start_date == '2018-01-01' & end_date == '2021-12-31'
and create a filtered dataframe.

I am having trouble creating a loop that I can use as a filter.
Can someone help please!

Comment: Are your using SQL statement or Pyspark API?

Comment: Have you tried `df.filter((df.start_date >= '2018-01-01') & (df.end_date <= '2021-12-31'))`

Comment: @JonathanLam I am using sql statement..

Comment: @XXavier That will just filter for all the dates in that time range. I am looking for a way to run for the first 7 days a month for every month within this time range. So it would be something like `df.filter((df.start_date >= '2018-01-01') & (df.end_date <= '2018-01-07'))`  I would have to manually run this for 36 weeks. I can't filter for all 36 weeks together because it is a huge table. I could run it with a wrapper and run concurrent jobs...

Comment: Your problem is no clear. This input table is the table you want to filter? What is your expected output? a filtered dataframe with the same structure? Do you want to pass a date as a parameter? Please, try to sctructure your problem with input and desired output with complete exemples so we can work on a solution for you